# Get the list filtered values of a datatable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I would like to get the list filtered values of a datatable, if my datatable shown a list of 50 elements and I put a filter in a column then my datatable shown only 20 elements when I put a value in the filter, How I can get only the list of 20 elements in the bean for working with her

my code:

```
    <p:dataTable id="idDtListaOC" var="orden" value="#{ordenCompraBean.lstOrdenCompra}" 
     paginator="true" rows="10"  rowIndexVar="row" rowKey="#{orden.id}"
     paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown} "  
     rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
     filteredValue="#{ordenCompraBean.lstOrdenCompraFiltrado}"
     selection="#{ordenCompraBean.ocVista}" selectionMode="single">

    <p:column width="25px;" style="text-align: center;" >
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputLabel value="Nro"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{row+1}"/>
    </p:column>

    <p:column width="60px;" style="text-align: center;" sortBy="#{orden.strNumeroOrden}" filterBy="#{orden.strNumeroOrden}" filterMatchMode="contains">  
        <f:facet name="header">  
            <h:outputText value="Numero" />  
        </f:facet>  
        <h:outputText value="#{orden.strNumeroOrden}" />  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column headerText="Id" filterBy="#{orden.strProveedor}" filterMatchMode="contains" sortBy="#{orden.strProveedor}">
        <h:outputText value="#{orden.strProveedor}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you already have the filtered values in whatever you put in `filteredValue`, which means in `ordenCompraBean.lstOrdenCompraFiltrado`.